# Из текста получить ФИО

Tags: python-3.x, docx

```
from docx import Document
document_b = Document("титульный лист ВКР.docx")
for table in document_b.tables:
    for row in table.rows:
        for cell in row.cells:
            a = cell.text
            print(a)
```

Из этого кода у меня получился вот такой текст:

```
Разработал:       студент                    СЖДт – 523
Разработал:       студент                    СЖДт – 523
Разработал:       студент                    СЖДт – 523
Анищенко С.С.
 (должность, звание)
(группа)
(подпись)    (дата)
(ф., и., о.)




Руководитель: доцент, к.т.н.
Руководитель: доцент, к.т.н.
Руководитель: доцент, к.т.н.
Скутина О.Л.
 (должность, звание)
 (должность, звание)
(подпись)    (дата)
(ф., и., о.)




Руководитель: доцент, к.т.н.
Руководитель: доцент, к.т.н.
Руководитель: доцент, к.т.н.
Скутина О.Л.
 (должность, звание)
 (должность, звание)
(подпись)    (дата)
(ф., и., о.)
```

Из этого текста нужно получить ФИО студента и преподавателя. Ожидаемый результат:

```
Анищенко С.С.
Скутина О.Л.
```

Как можно этого достичь?

Answer (score 2):

Нужно уточнить критерии.

Пока видно такой критерий - если строка начинается с `Разработал:`, а следующая - нет, то добавить её к результату. Псевдокод:

```
 if line.startswith("Разработал:"):
       Wanted = True
 else:
      if Wanted:
            result.append(line) 
      Wanted = False
```